# Python equivalent of JavaScript property shorthand?

Tags: python

I love ES6's property shorthand for object literals:

```
var x = 5, y = 6;
var obj = { x, y };
```

I often wish something similar was possible for keyword arguments in python:

```
x = 5
y = 6
f(x=x, y=y)  # I wish there was a shorthand here
```

It's *sort of* possible if I abuse how python handles positional and keyword args in functions I define:

```
def f(x=None, y=None):
    print x
    print y
f(x, y)  # works
```

But that's brittle/inflexible, and it doesn't work on functions I commonly use, like `format()`:

```
'{x} {y}'.format(x, y)  # KeyError
```

Is there any syntatic sugar I'm missing, or is this just the limits of python?

Comment: You don't need to use default parameter values *at all*. `def f(x, y): ...` then `f(x, y)` works too.

Comment: @martijn yes, of course. I'm specifically talking about functions where I already do/must use keyword arguments for separate reasons.

Comment: And calls != creating an object. Sure, calling a class creates an object, but it's just another call as far as Python is concerned. That's different  from creating a JS object.

Comment: @martijn also, yes, I understand that perfectly, I'm saying the syntax of lining up a keyword with its value, in the case where the value is stored in a variable of the same name, is _syntactically similar_, not semantically identical, to javascript property shorthand.

Comment: You seem to be stuck on Python 2. Python 3 has `f'{x} {y}'`. Switching would be advisable; official support for Python 2 is planned to cut off in 2020.

Comment: @user2357112 ah! This is very interesting, thank you. I'm on App Engine standard environment, so I am less familiar with python 3. I would accept this as an answer. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings